# Background image doesn't cover when scrolling down page and new content is added

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background

I'm creating a simple To Do list that allows user to add and remove items. Everything works exactly how I want it to....EXCEPT.... my background images on two main columns no longer appear when user adds enough items to cause page to start scrolling. I though background-image repeat would work, but it doesn't.

**HTML** ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0d2a2061f5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/todo.css">

    <script defer src= "./static/JS/toDo.js"> </script>
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>
<body>

    
</div>

<div class="container0">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="title col-12">
                
                <h1>To Do List</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="title col-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span>
                    <div class="submit" id="submitbutton">
                        <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter new task here" maxlength="40">
                        <button id="enter">Add</button>                                     
                    </div>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>



<div class="container1">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col pic1">
            <div class="usertextbox">
                <div class="usertext">
                    <h2>Active</h2>

                    <ul id="activeTaskList">
                
                    </ul>

                </div>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>

        <div class="col pic2">
            <div class="usertextbox">
                <div class="usertext">
                    <h2>
                        Completed
                    </h2> 
            
                    <ul id="completedTaskList">
                
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>






</body>
</html>
```

**JS** ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
// assigning variable to the add task button
var addTask = document.getElementById("enter");
//assigning variable to input user enters in the add new task input section
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
// returns the element that matches the CSS selector of 'ul' (vs the ID for getElementbyID)
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
// created variable to assign to ul where I will append completed tasks 
var completedTasks = document.getElementById("completedTaskList");


// simple function that calculates length of user input(really just making sure it's > 0)
function inputLength () {
return input.value.length;
}

// function to create new task list item and corresponding delete button
function newTaskList() {
// var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
// assigning variable to the li item we are creating when function is ran
var li = document.createElement("li");
var completedLi = document.createElement("li");
//appending the user's input value to the li element we just created
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
//now appending that li with the user input to the ul(we assigned ul variable to the ul in document using queryselector)
ul.appendChild(li);
// clearing input value of user when function is ran 
var completed = input.value;
input.value = "";
// assigning the creation of delete button to the deleteButton variable 
var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
// styling that delete button
deleteButton.style.border = 'none'
deleteButton.style.transition = "all .3s ease-in-out";
deleteButton.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff'
deleteButton.style.margin = '20px'

//adding event listeners to grow and remove grow when item is hovered with mouse
deleteButton.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
deleteButton.classList.add('grow')
})
deleteButton.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
deleteButton.classList.remove('grow')
})

//assigning text to delete button with createTextNode
deleteButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("️"))
// appending the delete button to each li that is created 
li.appendChild(deleteButton);
// creating function that gives us access to parent element of delete button (which is li)
// and deletes it when we click delete
deleteButton.onclick = function() {
completedLi.style.textDecoration = 'line-through'
completedTasks.appendChild(completedLi);
completedLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(completed));
this.parentElement.style.display = "none";
}
}

//creating function that indicates to run addTaskList only if length of input from user is >0(they actually wrote something)
function addTaskList() {
if (inputLength() > 0) {
newTaskList();
}
}

// create event listener to have addTaskList function run if user clicks on add task button (variable we already created assinged to id of add button)
addTask.addEventListener("click", addTaskList);
```

**CSS** ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
* {
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    }

/* Main title and text box/button ------------------------ */

.container0{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: rgb(189, 174, 172);
}

.title {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
margin-top: 20px;
}

h1 {
position: relative;
bottom: -15px;
transition: all .7s ease-in-out; 
}

h1:hover {
transform: scale(1.3); 
}

#enter {
border-radius: 50%;
height: 50px;
width: 70px;
font-size: 1.2rem;
font-weight: bolder;
background-color: rgb(173, 207, 238);
border: 3px solid rgb(99, 94, 93);
border-style: solid;
padding: 4px;
margin: 5px;
}

.input-group {
height: 5vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
max-width: 400px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
position:relative;
left: 25px;
}

input {
height: 35px;
width: 250px;
}

#enter:hover {
background-color: rgb(15, 15, 238);
color: white;
border-color: white;
}

/* Main body columns and inner divs ------------------------ */

.container1{
margin: 5px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}


.pic1 {
background-image: url("../images/todo.jpg");
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: repeat;
height: 100vh;
font-weight: bolder;
padding: 0px;
margin-right: 2.5px;
margin-left: 10px;
}

.pic2 {
background-image: url("../images/done.jpg");
background-size: 100% 100%;
height: 100vh;
font-weight: bolder;
padding: 0px;
margin-left: 2.5px;
margin-right: 10px;
}

.usertextbox {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0.8;
height: 100vh;
}

.usertext {
width: 500px;
margin: 5%;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000000;
}

/* Titles and lists in active and completed columns ------------------------ */

h2 {
position: relative;
right: -175px;
bottom: 15px;
width: fit-content;
padding: 15px;
background-color:rgb(173, 207, 238);
border-radius: 50%;
border-color: rgb(99, 94, 93);
border-style: solid;
border-width: 3.5px;
}

h2:hover {
background-color: rgb(15, 15, 238);
color: white;
}

li {
font-size: 1.1rem;
padding: 2px; 
position:relative;
left: -30px;
height: 50px;
}

.completedLi {
font-size: 3.1rem;
padding: 2px; 
position:relative;
left: -30px;
height: 60px;
}

.grow {
transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve is parallax scrolling. It should be enough to add this CSS to your image:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

For more information look here: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp)

I added the CSS to your snippet but I'm not sure if it works as the image is a relative path and not existent on StackOverflow's servers.

```js
// assigning variable to the add task button
var addTask = document.getElementById("enter");
//assigning variable to input user enters in the add new task input section
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
// returns the element that matches the CSS selector of 'ul' (vs the ID for getElementbyID)
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
// created variable to assign to ul where I will append completed tasks 
var completedTasks = document.getElementById("completedTaskList");


// simple function that calculates length of user input(really just making sure it's > 0)
function inputLength () {
return input.value.length;
}

// function to create new task list item and corresponding delete button
function newTaskList() {
// var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
// assigning variable to the li item we are creating when function is ran
var li = document.createElement("li");
var completedLi = document.createElement("li");
//appending the user's input value to the li element we just created
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
//now appending that li with the user input to the ul(we assigned ul variable to the ul in document using queryselector)
ul.appendChild(li);
// clearing input value of user when function is ran 
var completed = input.value;
input.value = "";
// assigning the creation of delete button to the deleteButton variable 
var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
// styling that delete button
deleteButton.style.border = 'none'
deleteButton.style.transition = "all .3s ease-in-out";
deleteButton.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff'
deleteButton.style.margin = '20px'

//adding event listeners to grow and remove grow when item is hovered with mouse
deleteButton.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
deleteButton.classList.add('grow')
})
deleteButton.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
deleteButton.classList.remove('grow')
})

//assigning text to delete button with createTextNode
deleteButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("️"))
// appending the delete button to each li that is created 
li.appendChild(deleteButton);
// creating function that gives us access to parent element of delete button (which is li)
// and deletes it when we click delete
deleteButton.onclick = function() {
completedLi.style.textDecoration = 'line-through'
completedTasks.appendChild(completedLi);
completedLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(completed));
this.parentElement.style.display = "none";
}
}

//creating function that indicates to run addTaskList only if length of input from user is >0(they actually wrote something)
function addTaskList() {
if (inputLength() > 0) {
newTaskList();
}
}

// create event listener to have addTaskList function run if user clicks on add task button (variable we already created assinged to id of add button)
addTask.addEventListener("click", addTaskList);
```

```css
* {
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    }

/* Main title and text box/button ------------------------ */

.container0{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: rgb(189, 174, 172);
height: 100%;
}

.title {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
margin-top: 20px;
}

h1 {
position: relative;
bottom: -15px;
transition: all .7s ease-in-out; 
}

h1:hover {
transform: scale(1.3); 
}

#enter {
border-radius: 50%;
height: 50px;
width: 70px;
font-size: 1.2rem;
font-weight: bolder;
background-color: rgb(173, 207, 238);
border: 3px solid rgb(99, 94, 93);
border-style: solid;
padding: 4px;
margin: 5px;
}

.input-group {
height: 5vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
max-width: 400px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
position:relative;
left: 25px;
}

input {
height: 35px;
width: 250px;
}

#enter:hover {
background-color: rgb(15, 15, 238);
color: white;
border-color: white;
}

/* Main body columns and inner divs ------------------------ */

.container1{
margin: 5px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100%;
}


.pic1 {
 

   background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594482627762-6e876ce1ead4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=774&q=80);
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 100%;
font-weight: bolder;
padding: 0px;
margin-right: 2.5px;
margin-left: 10px;
min-height: 100vw;
}

.pic2 {
background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594482627762-6e876ce1ead4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=774&q=80);
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 100%;
font-weight: bolder;
padding: 0px;
margin-left: 2.5px;
margin-right: 10px;
min-height: 100vw;
}

.usertextbox {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0.8;
height: 100%;
}

.usertext {
width: 500px;
margin: 5%;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000000;
height: 100%
}

/* Titles and lists in active and completed columns ------------------------ */

h2 {
position: relative;
right: -175px;
bottom: 15px;
width: fit-content;
padding: 15px;
background-color:rgb(173, 207, 238);
border-radius: 50%;
border-color: rgb(99, 94, 93);
border-style: solid;
border-width: 3.5px;
}

h2:hover {
background-color: rgb(15, 15, 238);
color: white;
}

li {
font-size: 1.1rem;
padding: 2px; 
position:relative;
left: -30px;
height: 50px;
}

.completedLi {
font-size: 3.1rem;
padding: 2px; 
position:relative;
left: -30px;
height: 60px;
}

.grow {
transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0d2a2061f5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/todo.css">

    <script defer src= "./static/JS/toDo.js"> </script>
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>
<body>

    
</div>

<div class="container0">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="title col-12">
                
                <h1>To Do List</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="title col-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span>
                    <div class="submit" id="submitbutton">
                        <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter new task here" maxlength="40">
                        <button id="enter">Add</button>                                     
                    </div>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>



<div class="container1">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col pic1">
            <div class="usertextbox">
                <div class="usertext">
                    <h2>Active</h2>

                    <ul id="activeTaskList">
                
                    </ul>

                </div>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>

        <div class="col pic2">
            <div class="usertextbox">
                <div class="usertext">
                    <h2>
                        Completed
                    </h2> 
            
                    <ul id="completedTaskList">
                
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>






</body>
</html>
```

Hope I could help ;)

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to try to help me out! Very kind. Unfortunately, it still isn't working : ( I tried the CSS you recommended and several variations of it and read the W3 docs, but I'm not sure it's a parallax scrolling issue. Basically, when user adds enough new tasks to cause the page to start scrolling, the image is cut off and doesn't repeat beyond the original page size.

Comment: that's weird but it works for me after you edited the post (at least on the left site)

Comment: Oh, I know what you mean... The reason for this is, that the container has a set height of 100vh which is the screen height... I'll edit the post to match the problem

Comment: ok it should work now - let me know if not

Comment: thanks, I also found adding: overflow-y: scroll; to the user-text class fixes it as well!

Comment: Nice :) Could you mark the question as answered so it won't pop up in the list of unanswered questions?